# A dress code during a freelance interview?

Tags: interview, dress-code

I have been interviewed lately and during the interview a client told me that he liked my interview dress code. I was quite surprised since I had nothing special but a polo-shirt. I asked the client why he complimented my outfit since I was not wearing a tie, and he told me that his previous interviewer appeared on Skype interview in his undershirt (!). I was interviewed for a position which required a very experienced individual so I was surprised by his statement even more.

**How should a freelance candidate be dressed for a freelance Skype (or any other similar conferencing app) interview, and how can one tell what's appropriate and what isn't?**

I am here asking about Skype interview only, not about meeting the client face to face.

Comment: Hey Peter, in regards to tag wiki excerpts, remember that the goal is to describe ***when to use the tag on a question***. Instead, I'd use the tag wiki *body* as the area to define specific terms, highlight good example questions, and elaborate further on the subject in question. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks, did not know that!

Comment: Maybe replace "Skype" with videoconferencing (or video telecommunication, video telephony, …)? Skype is a proprietary product, and there are many other ways how to have a video interview. Your question would apply to all of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it ultimately depends on how you want to market yourself and the industry. As a freelancer or contractor, you're ultimately the president, CEO and busybody. 
Based on that, use your best judgement as to how you want others to perceive you as a brand. If you're trying to speak to clients that are in the healthcare or financial industry, i would field their expectations accordingly.

The other factor to put into play is the industry that you're in. If you're a freelance painter, it might not make sense to wear a suit and tie.

In the end, dressing and fashion is an art. If you're making a conscience decision on your attire feel confident about it and go with it and dress comfortably so that it supports your personality and you.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to make a good impression but not go over the top. I would aim to dress at least as smartly as peers might dress for an interview.

Expected dress standards will vary depending on the location and the type of work.

For example, as a remote office worker in Australia, I'd expect to at least wear a collared shirt or perhaps a polo shirt with a company logo. A tie would probably be over the top here unless dealing with a large corporate Sydney client.